# How to move punctuation from the start or middle of a string to the end

Tags: javascript, regex

I've got a Pig Latin translator that I've set up to take single or multi-word strings, but it can't do punctuation.

As it is, `translatePigLatin("Pig Latin");` returns `'Igpay Atinlay'`, as it should, but `translatePigLatin("Pig Latin.");` returns `'Igpay Atin.lay'`, with the period annoyingly in the middle of a word. How do I make it return `'Igpay Atinlay.'` instead?

The function is:

```
function translatePigLatin(string) {
  var arr = string.split(' ');
  var str;
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var j = 0;
    if (!/[\d]/.test(arr[i])) {
      while (/[^aeiou]/i.test(arr[i][j])) {
        j++;
      }
      if (j > 0) {
        arr[i] = arr[i].slice(j) + arr[i].slice(0, j) + 'ay';
      } else {
        arr[i] = arr[i] + 'way';
      }
    }
    if (/[A-Z]/.test(arr[i])) {
      arr[i] = toTitleCase(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  return arr.join(' ');
}

function toTitleCase(str) {
  return str.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
    return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1).toLowerCase();
  });
}
```

Comment: collect + remove all none-alpha characters from the input string, then at the end of the routine append those none-alpha characters to the end of the string.

Comment: @marcusshep I uinderstand that that's what I need to do but I am having trouble doing it correctly.

Comment: You got this, I believe in you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
function punct(str)
{
  var punctuation = ".,!@#$";
  var matches = 0;
  for(var i=0;i<str.length-matches;i++)
  {
    if(punctuation.indexOf(str[i])!=-1)
    {
      str = str.substr(0,i) + str.substr(i+1)+str[i--];
      matches++;
    }
  }
  return str;
}
```

which loops through your string using a for loop and if it finds a character within the punctuation string, it moves that character at the end of the string.So punct("Igpay Atin.lay") yields "Igpay Atinlay.".Give it a shot.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much! I had done something like this earlier when I was trying to do this myself, but what I had was just close enough to still give a REALLY wrong answer.

Comment: @alton1231 No problem.The tricky part of this iterative solution is that for every match you find,aside from moving it at the end of the string ,you also have to reduce by one the number of character that your for loop will process, thus you got str.length-matches.Otherwise your loop will also process the punctuation that has already been transfered at the end,which is something we don't want