# Javascript Pig Latin punctuation appearing in middle of words instead of the end

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a practice project where we have to create an English to Pig Latin translator. However, when there is punctuation involved such as ! or ?, it ends up making it appear in the middle of the last word instead of staying that the end of the word. I'm not sure how to approach this.

For example, if I type "There are no pizzas" it returns "ere-Thay are-yay o-nay izzas?-pay"

```js
const textInput = document.getElementById("textInput");
const textOutput = document.getElementById("textOutput");
const vowels = ["a", "e", "i", "o", "u", "A", "E", "I", "O", "U"];
const ending = "-yay";

textInput.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  const input = e.target.value;
  const words = input.split(" ");
  const output = words.map((word) => pigLatinConverter(word)).join(" ");
  textOutput.innerText = output;
});

const pigLatinConverter = (input) => {
  if (vowels.includes(input[0])) {
    output = input + ending;
  } else {
    let consonants = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
      if (vowels.includes(input[i])) {
        break;
      }
      if (input[i] === "-ay") {
        input[i] === " ";
      }
      consonants += input[i];
    }
    if (consonants === "") {
      output = input.substring(consonants.length) + " ";
    } else {
      output = input.substring(consonants.length) + `-${consonants}ay`;
    }
  }
  return output;
};
```

```html
<input id="textInput" />
<p id="textOutput"></p>
```

Comment: Well, you'll have to start by detecting the punctuation marks. You can do this with an array as you did with the vowels, but you'd have to include all punctuation marks ever. A more thorough way would be to enter the dark domain of regular expressions (It's dangerous to go alone. Take this: https://regex101.com/). Once you can detect the punctuation, just split it from the string and, as the final step, concat it back on.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45966378/how-to-move-punctuation-from-the-start-or-middle-of-a-string-to-the-end

Comment: Thank you to both. Went with the overflow link but I really gotta get used to regex